# Load balancing onto replicas of pods

Tags: kubernetes, devops, azure-aks

We have an AKS cluster and we want to achieve below two points in our architecture:

1. We have replicas of pods and we want to have only 1 request served by one pod. **basically one pod - one request design.**
2. When all pods are busy, then next coming request should not be queued **at POD level**, instead it should  be queued at **service level** and once any of busy pod become idle or available then only queued request should be dispatched on idle pod.

How to achieve above things?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Which version of Kubernetes did you use? What did you try to achive #1 point? What is the current status?

Comment: kubernetes version is 1.8.8. do not have any solution to design #1 point

Comment: You are using very very old version of Kubernetes. Actual stable version is 1.21. Look at the [releases](https://kubernetes.io/releases/) page.

Comment: sorry my mistake Kubernetes version is 1.18.8 . I missed 1 in 18 digit.

Comment: You need to write a custom proxy with access to the Kubernetes API that can create new pods on demand; this is not a standard Kubernetes setup.  This is also an extremely heavy-weight setup (if it takes tens of seconds to pull and deploy a new pod you can hit HTTP request timeouts very easily) and every Web framework supports handling multiple requests per process.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this could be achieved by creating a custom proxy that creates pods on demand, but in practice it will be very difficult and performance will be poor. This was very well explained by David Maze in his comment:

> You need to write a custom proxy with access to the Kubernetes API that can create new pods on demand; this is not a standard Kubernetes setup. This is also an extremely heavy-weight setup (if it takes tens of seconds to pull and deploy a new pod you can hit HTTP request timeouts very easily) and every Web framework supports handling multiple requests per process.